# how to lock mdi form when click logout button?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have two form log in and MDI Parent form. When I log in, its show MDI Parent form. There is 1 button log out. When I press log out then log in form show and MDI Parent form hide. I want MDI Parent form lock back end and log in form at front. how to lock MDI Parent form to input or click?

Comment: Every Winforms app already has a logout button, it is at the far upper right of the window.  And the user already logs in as well, right after he starts his machine.

Comment: have you tried disabling your Parent Form before you Hide it. `Me.Enabled = False` or `this.Enabled = false` depending on if you are using c# or vb.net

Comment: yep disable function is work but i want to lock MDI parent form that user can't click that just log in form shows at front

Comment: Try using `Login.ShowDialog(Me)` or `Login.ShowDialog(this)` depending on if you are using vb.net or c#, this will show your Login Form as a Modal Dialog Box, with your ParentForm as owner, that should prevent the parent form from coming to the Forefront. I am making the assumption that the Login form **is not** a MDI Child but a separate form.